# Sphinx and friend search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, has-many-through, thinking-sphinx

I have a high-level question about Sphinx on Ruby on Rails:

Say I want to search are the articles written by my friends.
The model structure would be:

```
User has_many users :through relationships
Article belongs_to User
```

My question is: what sort of syntax would I use on Sphinx so the user searches for articles and gets only the articles written by his friends? I am having trouble finding this online and I'd like to have a handle on how this would work before I implement my solution.

NOTE: I suspect one solution is to have an array of friend IDs and then use a :condition :with => {:id => array_of_friendIDs}. But maybe there is a more effective way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically correct - you're going to need to assemble an array of friend ids and pass it to the search, using the `:with` option. How you fetch that list isn't particularly related to Sphinx, though.

```
friend_ids = current_user.users.pluck(:id)

@articles = Article.search(params['search_term'], :with => {:user_id => friend_ids})
```

Using `.pluck` will save you a good bit of time that would otherwise be devoted to instantiating a bunch of User objects - you only need their ids. Make sure that you've set `user_id` as an attribute for Sphinx (using `has user_id` in the `define_index` block).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this MrTheWalrus